# Template does not exist django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

What I have done is put multiple apps into another app. I have them talking to each other though the name system. I still have to do foreign keys and all for the databases.

However I have a route in my `urls.py` on the couresapp and a view for the same rendering and taking me to the page. When I click the catalog button on the success page it gives me an error that page cannot be found.

Hoping a second pair of eyes can see and fix this :

**urls.py for courses app**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', views.index, name= 'index'),
  url(r'^user$', views.create, name='success'),
  url(r'^usercourses$', views.usercourses, name='usercourses')
]
```

**views.py for courses app**

```
def usercourses(request):


    context ={

        "courses": User.objects.all(),

    }

    return render (request, "coursesapp/users_courses.html", context )
```

**html for coures app**

```
   <body>
        <form class="" action="{% url 'courses:usercourses' %}" method="post">

      <p>  Test <option value="{{user.course_name}}"></option> Test
        Test <option value="{{user.course_name}}"></option> Test


            <input type="submit" name="" value="Add">
        </form>

  {% for user in courses%}
     <p>{{user.course_name}} {{user.description}} {{created_at.description}}</p>
      {% endfor%}

    </body>
```

**html for the form in the success page in the login app that takes me to the  courses app**

```
    <form class="" action="{% url 'courses:usercourses' %}"  method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" name="Logout" value="Catalog">
    </form>

</html>
```

Traceback sorry fogot to include this

```
Template loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\django2\multiapps\multiapps\apps\coursesapp\templates\coursesapp\users_courses.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\django2\multiapps\multiapps\apps\logReg\templates\coursesapp\users_courses.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\django2\multiapps\multiapps\apps\manyapps\templates\coursesapp\users_courses.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\coursesapp\users_courses.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\coursesapp\users_courses.html (Source does not exist)



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  42.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\django2\multiapps\multiapps\apps\coursesapp\views.py" in usercourses
  34.   return render (request, "coursesapp/users_courses.html", context )

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  67.         template = get_template(template_name, using=using)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in get_template
  25.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /courses/usercourses Exception Value: coursesapp/users_courses.html
```

Comment: Show the full traceback please.

Comment: The template "coursesapp/users_courses.html" does not exist in its expected path. Check your template_dirs settings and make sure the template exists. Normally the django error page shows all pathes where it has been looking for the template...

Comment: Its there other html files in the folder work

Comment: You haven't included enough information to debug the problem. As Jingo says, the full error message will give a hint what the problem is. We can't help because we don't know the layout of your project files or your `TEMPLATES` settings.

Comment: Give me an hour and ill upload more

Comment: Make sure the file C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\django2\multiapps\multiapps\apps\coursesapp\templates\coursesapp\users_courses.html is on the disk, in the right path

Comment: C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\django2\multiapps\multiapps\apps\coursesapp\templates\courseapp  its in that folder

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the issue was an extra s in courses

Comment: Accept your answer then since you found it!

Answer (score 0):

In views.py directory, put the path since C: until your template folder, and use double backslashes*

*because \u is a Unicode escape

```
 return render(request,"C:\\Users\\You\\templates\\test.html",{})
```